# How to clone similar element when checkbox change using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, clone

I currently have a number of items each with a list of data inside. What I'm trying to achieve is, when i select a checkbox that has the same matching attribute of `itemName`, the matching div that contains the additional data is appended to a container. I have written some code up here:

```
<div class="item" itemName="itemOne">
    <h2> Item One </h2>
    <ul>
        <li> Data 1 </li>
        <li> Data 2 </li>
        <li> Data 3 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="item" itemName="itemTwo">
    <h2> Item Two </h2>
    <ul>
        <li> Data 1 </li>
        <li> Data 2 </li>
        <li> Data 3 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul class="itemSelection">
    <li itemName="itemOne">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>Item One</label>
    </li>
    <li itemName="itemTwo">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>Item Two</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you  tried?

Comment: Storing the checkbox attribute value as a variable, and if it matches that of the div. then append the div. not much luck at the moment.

Comment: Please add the code you tried to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check state of checkbox. If checkbox is `checked` use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to adding target element to `#container` and if it is `unchecked` use [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to deleting it.

```js
$(".itemSelection :checkbox").change(function(){
    var itemName = $(this).closest("li").attr("itemName");
    if (this.checked)
        $(".item[itemName=" + itemName + "]").clone().appendTo("#container");
    else
        $("#container .item[itemName=" + itemName + "]").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" itemName="itemOne">
    <h2> Item One </h2>
    <ul>
        <li> Data 1 </li>
        <li> Data 2 </li>
        <li> Data 3 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="item" itemName="itemTwo">
    <h2> Item Two </h2>
    <ul>
        <li> Data 1 </li>
        <li> Data 2 </li>
        <li> Data 3 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul class="itemSelection">
    <li itemName="itemOne">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>Item One</label>
    </li>
    <li itemName="itemTwo">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>Item Two</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Mohammad, thank you a million for the clean and concise code. Much appreciated and exactly what I came here for. Massively appreciated.

Comment: Why was my post down voted? I'm not entirely sure what was wrong with a legitimate question.

Comment: @MegaTron I didn't down voted your post but maybe it is because you didn't try any code and only posted an question.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mohammad. My bad, I came here because I didn't know how to do it or where to start. I thought it was a forum for assistance. Next time I'll state that I'm not entirely sure where to start. Eitherway, I appreciate your working answer :)